# not able to add routes in aurelia.js

Tags: aurelia

Not able get routes even though added routes in app.js.
I am using below code to navigate to route. But getting error saying no route available.

```
this.router.navigateToRoute(‘Summary’, { replace: true, trigger: true });
```

app.js code:

````
import { inject } from ‘aurelia-framework’;

@inject(Element)
export class App {
constructor(element) {
debugger
this.element = element;
this.Id = null;
this.message = ‘App’;
if (element)
this.Id = element.dataset[‘id’];
}
configureRouter(config, router) {
config.title = ‘App’;

    config.map([
        {
            route: 'Summary',
            name: 'Summary',
            moduleId: '../src/summary-control',
            nav: true
        },
        {
            route: 'Detail',
            name: 'Detail',
            moduleId:'../src/detail-control',
            nav: true,
            title: 'Details'
        },
    ]);
    this.router = router;
}
} ```
````

Comment: We have a similar thread on discourse as well, so lets continue this there, and then later copy paste the solution here